# Semantic UI React: how to conditionally set a Form.Input to readOnly

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to conditionally set a `Form.Input` depending on `selectedProfile` if it is not null, it will set the Input as `readOnly` but if not then it won't. 
this is my code and of course it didn't work. It would be easier if it's like `readOnly = true` but it's not

```
  render() {
  let readOnly = _.isNil(selectedProfile) ? "" : 'readOnly';

  return (
   <Form>
          <Form.Input
                fluid
                required
                label="First name"
                placeholder="Jose"
                name="firstName"
                value={ _.isNil(selectedProfile) ? this.state.firstName : selectedProfile.first_name }
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                {readOnly}
              />
   </Form>
```

for more info on `readOnly`, [here's semantic ui react's docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#states-field-read-only) about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to really provide a prop with true or false.

```
render() {
  return (
      <Form>
          <Form.Input
                fluid
                required
                label="First name"
                placeholder="Jose"
                name="firstName"
                value={ _.isNil(selectedProfile) ? this.state.firstName : selectedProfile.first_name }
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                // with this you are really passing true or false
                readOnly={!_.isNil(selectedProfile)}
              />
      </Form>
  }
```

Comment: ohhhh so even if I can use `readOnly` alone without true or false by default, `readOnly={!_.isNil(selectedProfile)}` does work when I need to do it conditionally. I have learned something valuable today. thanks

Comment: you should assign `_.isNil(selectedProfile)` to a var and reuse it

Answer (score 1):

You have to write it like this if `readOnly` value comes from a variable:

```
render() {
  let readOnly = !_.isNil(selectedProfile);

  return (
   <Form>
          <Form.Input
                fluid
                required
                label="First name"
                placeholder="Jose"
                name="firstName"
                value={ _.isNil(selectedProfile) ? this.state.firstName : selectedProfile.first_name }
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                readOnly={readOnly}
              />
   </Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid. A component expects `property=value`. In your case, you just put `property`. Also, `readOnly` expects a boolean, not a string. Change your code as following:

```
render() {
  return (
   <Form>
     <Form.Input
       fluid
       required
       label="First name"
       placeholder="Jose"
       name="firstName"
       value={ _.isNil(selectedProfile) ? this.state.firstName : selectedProfile.first_name }
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       readOnly={!_.isNil(selectedProfile)}
     />
   </Form>
}
```